# Installed Ubuntu. Can't even start the UGS Platform program

Tags: java

I've installed Ubuntu of a new mini pc I have and want to run the UGS Platform program. But no matter how much searching for solutions I've done, I can't to get this simple program to run. Runs fine of my two RPI's and my Windows PC.

Every time I try to run it, it keeps responding with "Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch". It came bundled with java.

I've installed java beyond what it was packaged with. Tried the jdkhome switch, etc., etc.

I've been at this for a month now and I still can't run the program. This was all I wanted Ubuntu to do when I first installed it. Run my CNC wood router. And if I can't get this program to run using Ubuntu then I'll be left moving onto another operating system.

I don't normally post on forums for answers to my questions because I can usually find them on online forums or other sites. But this one has left me totally confused and frustrated.

Any help that anyone can provide me to get this program to run would be more that appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

OS installed is from ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso downloaded from the Ubuntu site and installed via a USB flash drive.

Yes, the program I wish to run is UGS Platform. It does not require an installation. It just tells me it can't find Java when I try to start it.

echo $JAVE_HOME gives me the correct path.

Using  --jdkhome $JAVA_HOME returns the correct path but it still says it can't find java.

Hope this additional info helps.

Comment: Can you add more information? Start by telling us what version and flavour of Ubuntu you are using, where you obtained this software, and how you installed it.

Comment: i think this is the program the OP wants to install https://winder.github.io/ugs_website/guide/platform/

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting